# Conversion of CString to float

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, floating-point, cstring

Some body help me regarding to the following problem

```
strFixFactorSide = _T("0.5"); 
dFixFactorSide = atof((const char *)(LPCTSTR)strFixFactorSide);
```

"dFixFactorSide" takes value as 0.0000;

How I will get correct value?

Answer (score 1):

Use `_tstof()` instead of `atof()`, and cast CString to LPCTSTR, and leave it as such, instead of trying to get it to `const char *`. Forget about `const char *` (LPCSTR) while you're working with unicode and use only `const _TCHAR *` (LPCTSTR).

```
int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])
{
    int nRetCode = 0;

    CString s1 = _T("123.4");
    CString s2 = _T("567.8");

    double v1 = _tstof((LPCTSTR)s1);
    double v2 = _tstof((LPCTSTR)s2);

    _tprintf(_T("%.3f"), v1 + v2);

    return nRetCode;
}
```

and running this correctly gives the expected answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `CString strFixFactorSide` is a Unicode (UTF-16) string.

If it is, the cast `(const char *)` only changes the pointer type, but the string it points to still remains Unicode.

`atof()` doesn't work with Unicode strings. If you shove `L"0.5"` into it, it will fetch bytes 0x30 ('0') and 0x00 (also part of UTF-16 '0'), treat that as a NUL-terminated ASCII string `"0"` and convert it to 0.0.

If `CString strFixFactorSide` is a Unicode string, you need to either first convert it to an ASCII string and then apply `atof()` or use a function capable of converting Unicode strings to numbers. `_wtof()` can be used for Unicode strings.

Comment: I get error as "error C2065: '_wtof' : undeclared identifier". I use eVC++ 4.0

Comment: Did you try including `<stdio.h>`, `<wchar.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`, `<math.h>`? Others to try: `wcstod()` or `swscanf()`.

Comment: I got solution as below "_stscanf(strFixFactorSide, _T("%lf"), &dFixFactorSide);" But is this correct way?

Comment: I'd write `_stscanf((LPCTSTR)strFixFactorSide, _T("%lf"), &dFixFactorSide);`.